# The first UITableViewCell's accessary arrow is not showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here is the code I am struggling with, the first table cell doesnt display the accessary arrow, but other table cells work fine...

Below is the code for table cell1, other cells is also customized but work fine.

```
- (void) initialization
{
    labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    labelTitle.font = [UIFont fontForMoreLikeResultTitle];
    labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labelTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
    labelTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    labelFulLAddress = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    labelFulLAddress.font =  [UIFont fontForMoreLikeResultDescription];
    labelFulLAddress.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labelFulLAddress.numberOfLines = 1;
    labelFulLAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    labelFulLAddress.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [[self contentView] addSubview:labelTitle];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:labelFulLAddress];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        [self initialization];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    float xOffset = 20.0f;
    float yOffset = 10.0f;
    float currentUsedHeight = yOffset; 

    labelTitle.text = documentTitle;
    labelTitle.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, currentUsedHeight, 
                                  320.0f - 2 * xOffset, 60.0f);
    [labelTitle sizeToFitHeight];
    [labelTitle sizeToFitWidth];

    labelFulLAddress.text = @"99999 Bellevue Way NE, Bellevue WA";
    currentUsedHeight += (yOffset + labelTitle.frame.size.height);
    labelFulLAddress.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, currentUsedHeight, 320.0f - 2 * xOffset, 60.0f);
    [labelFulLAddress sizeToFitHeight];
    [labelFulLAddress sizeToFitWidth];
}
```

Below is the code in view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) createResultTableCell1:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FirstMoreLikeResultCell";
    FirstResultTableCell *cell = (FristResultTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MoreLikeTableCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.documentTitle = self.documentTitle;

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell = [self createResultTableCell1:tableView];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [self createResultTableCell2:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @MarkGranoff, thanks a lot for helping me formatting the messy code I posted :)

Comment: No problem. Just put it between <pre></pre> tags.

Comment: are you entering this code at all? this code is not written in such a good way...ideally you should not place one "return" inside an "if" and the other one outside.

Comment: Let's see the code for your UITableViewCells.  Maybe something going on there?

Comment: @TommyG yes, the code wasn't clean, but i just cleaned it and updated it.

Comment: @PeterCetinski i have a hard time to add the code for cell1 to the post :( but the code was really simple.

Comment: Are the cell classes starting form 1 the same class as `MoreLikeTableCell1` or are they different? You should definitely add more code..

Comment: @d.ennis I've added the code.
I only added TableViewCell code for the first cell since it's the one not working.

Comment: @PeterCetinski i figured out how to add the code, the code is posted now.

Comment: The evil thing is within the customized cell, but i cannot find it...If i use the default UITableViewCell, it works.

Comment: Is it possible that your layoutSubviews method ends up somehow hiding your accessoryView?

Comment: @PeterCetinski I tried to find out where and why the accessory view is hidden, but can't find the reason, tried to shrink the label width too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `[super layoutSubviews]` from within your **`overridden`** `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: god, you saved me! It's exactly what I missed! Thanks a lot!! ^____^